# PDO::__construct(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client

Tags: php, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Web utilizando a versão 3.1.9 do `Codeigniter`, porém estou com dificuldades na conexão com o banco de dados.

Segue configuração:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'mysql:host=localhost; port=3306; dbname=tarifador; charset=utf8',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '******',
    'database' => 'tarifador',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Erro apresentado:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: PDO::__construct(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers
Filename: pdo/pdo_driver.php
Line Number: 136
Backtrace:
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
A Database Error Occurred
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers
Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_driver.php
Line Number: 142
```

No banco de dados o Schema já está configurado como `UTF8 e UT8_general_ci`.

Já tentei também usar o driver do `mysqli`.

Detalhes adicionais:
Versão do PHP: 5.6.37
Versão do MySQL: 8.0.12

Grato a quem puder ajudar

Comment: Existe esse caso do SO. Se funcionar, considere em traduzir ele para o SOpt para ajudar mais colegas. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437490/pdo-construct-server-sent-charset-255-unknown-to-the-client-please-rep

Comment: Já tentei esta solução, porém o problema persiste.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi [nesta *issue* do PHP](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74461) o MySQL 8 tem como charset padrão o `utf8mb4` e segundo o último comentário estes problemas foram corrigidos no PHP 7.

> **[2018-05-02 17:37 UTC] macleo at outlook dot com**
>
> Should be fixed as of 7.0.19, 7.1.5, and 7.2.0. Anyone confirm? - yes

Visto que o PHP 5.x não reconhece este charset, a solução mais provável é que tuas tabelas devam ser alteradas para o charset `utf8`.